# how to center image and text in html

Tags: html

new in html, i'm trying to make the following structure..

```css
body {background-image: url("test.jpg"); color: red;}
h1 {text-align: center;}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  horizontal-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

.class {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>CSS_externo</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssestilo1.css">
<body>
<hr align="center" color="cyanblue" size="20" width="10%"/>
<hr align="center" color="cyan" size="16" width="8%"/>
<hr align="center" color="cyan" size="16" width="6%"/>
<hr align="center" color="cyan" size="16" width="4%"/>
<hr align="center" color="cyan" size="16" width="2%"/>
<hr align="center" color="cyan" size="16" width="4%"/>
<hr align="center" color="cyan" size="16" width="6%"/>
<hr align="center" color="cyan" size="16" width="8%"/>
<hr align="center" color="cyanblue" size="20" width="10%"/>
<h1>NO_________________TIME</h1></br>
<center>
<p>Can it be?</p>
<img src="flybat.gif" border="5">
<p class="test">npobody here</p>
</center>


</body>
</html>
```

i need both to be in the center of the page..

i need the image to be in the center how it is now, but the text that is below needs do be also in the center right to the image..

Answer (score 0):

Use **flexbox** `display:flex;justify-content:center` applied to a container inside of which you will place all the child elements you want to center.

In `html` create a `div` to enclosure the tag elements you want to be centered. Then assign a `class` to it, let's say `class="my-centered"`. Then in `css` place this code `.centered {display:flex;justify-content:center}`

Sorry if I am not placing the whole code here but I am on my mobile and editing options are very limited in this version of Stack Overflow.

Comment: i am really kinda getting the structure of it all.. can you insert this on the code? i dont know how to use it at all.

Comment: Then you might want to consider to select the answer and up vote it too. It's been a pleasure to be able to help!

Answer (score 0):

i got a new deal here

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>CSS_externo</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssestilo1.css">
<body>
<hr align="center" color="cyanblue" size="20" width="10%"/>
<hr align="center" color="cyan" size="16" width="8%"/>
<hr align="center" color="cyan" size="16" width="6%"/>
<hr align="center" color="cyan" size="16" width="4%"/>
<hr align="center" color="cyan" size="16" width="2%"/>
<hr align="center" color="cyan" size="16" width="4%"/>
<hr align="center" color="cyan" size="16" width="6%"/>
<hr align="center" color="cyan" size="16" width="8%"/>
<hr align="center" color="cyanblue" size="20" width="10%"/>
<h1>NO_________________TIME</h1></br>
<p>Can it be?</p>
<div class="centered">
<img src="flybat.gif" border="5">
<p>Nobody here</br></p>
<p>Nobody there</p>
<p>Nobody out</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

the phrases nobody are all in one single line..

Comment: Just use a single `p` tag and a couple of `br` after 1rst and 2nd phrases, then, in `css` you should state `.centered p {text-align:center}` it should give every phrase a new line and all of them centered on the container.